# selected Value from drop down is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am trying to fetch the value from web API and updating it to adapter. I got the value from API and its also showing in the drop down, but when i select any value from drop down its not showing the selected value

here is my code:-

```
public class ApplyLeave extends BaseActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

List<String>Leavetype=new ArrayList<String>();
String selState=null;// variable used for store the value of selected value in drop down
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

    context=this;

    getLeaveType();// method fetching the value from API and updating it in leaveType
   final Spinner spinerLeavetype = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spLeavetype);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Leavetype);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinerLeavetype.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinerLeavetype.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void getLeaveType()
{

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LeaveTypeResponse jsonResponse=ServiceManager.CompanyLeaveType(context,app);

            if(jsonResponse!=null){

                    if(jsonResponse.Response!=null){
                        for(Leave leaveTypeName:jsonResponse.Response)
                        {
                            Leavetype.add(leaveTypeName.Name);// here Leavetype is updating with value

                        }
                   }
            }
            else{
                CommonTasks.ShowToast(getApplicationContext(),handler,getString(R.string.NETWORKCONNECTIONEXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
            }

        }
    }).start();

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    selState= String.valueOf(adapterView.getSelectedItem());// selected value storing in selState variable .

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}


}
```

while the drop-down is working with hard-corded values like

```
 string[] Leavetype=new String[]{"Medical","Casual"};
```

Please anyone tell me where i am doing wrong .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake just apply adapter after data retrieved from websrvice like this

```
private void getLeaveType()
    {

        new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LeaveTypeResponse jsonResponse=ServiceManager.CompanyLeaveType(context,app);

                if(jsonResponse!=null){

                    if(jsonResponse.Response!=null){
                        for(Leave leaveTypeName:jsonResponse.Response)
                        {
                            Leavetype.add(leaveTypeName.Name);// here Leavetype is updating with value

                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                spinerLeavetype.setAdapter(adapter);
                                spinerLeavetype.setOnItemSelectedListener(ApplyLeave.this);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else{
                    CommonTasks.ShowToast(getApplicationContext(),handler,getString(R.string.NETWORKCONNECTIONEXCEPTION_MESSAGE));
                }

            }
        }).start();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks its working for me..but can you tell me what was the issue.

Comment: Yes sure because the getLeaveType() is running in background thread and you ware setting the adapter and listener before data fetched from the server.